# Howto see both git and svn operations in Team menu in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, svn

I have code on company-wide svn server. However, sometimes I want to use git to manage my local hacking and commit to svn later when there is some working code available.

So the normal workflow is to checkout code from svn (`svn co http://svnserver/svn/project`), cd to the project, run `git flow init -d`, create some feature branches and to start working.

After some prototyping (quite intense git flow local branching, committing, etc.) I can see the right way and I am ready to commit to svn too.

When I am working from command line only everything works fine.

Problem is when I want to use Eclipse (latest v4.5 Mars, but the problem is related to older releases too) to work with svn - there is no svn related stuff in project's team menu, but only the git menu items.

While there is .git directory, the git client takes priority and the Eclipse is displaying the git submenu only.

After renaming .git to .git2 the Eclipse's subversive menu appears and I am able to commit to svn from Eclipse.

**The question is**: it it possible to define vcs priority in Eclipse? It would be nice to define that svn have higher priority than git and if there is both .svn and .git in project's root, the .svn should be considered first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change priority, but you can unshare the project with 'Team -> Unshare' followed by 'Team -> Share' and using the subversive variation instead.